# How to recover users from ntds.dit

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

My primary (and single) DC died by mistake (not booting) however all the files are intact. What are my options to restore users on new DC on other server?

died DC: Windows server 2008 R2

Comment: Do you have a System State backup or a Full system backup of the Domain Controller? If not, then there's no way to recover and restore Active Directory from the dead server.

Comment: @joeqwerty unfortunately, there is no backup

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options:

1) if you're sure your files are intact, get that machine to boot by replacing hardware.

2) If not so sure; restore that machine from backup (you're basically performing a disaster recovery at this point) to alternate hardware.  Depending on your bare-metal product, this could be *good fun*.

You cannot however, copy those .dit files to another machine and just resume BAU operations with a new copy of your domain.

Microsoft best practise is to have two domain controllers on each AD 'Site' and at least one GC server at each AD site as well.

Good luck - sounds like you are possibly in for a late night.

Comment: ps, once you're up and running again it's your priority to have backups and a second DC - even if it's a VM running from a physically secure PC.  You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: thank you for reply. We are a small company, so there's no big deal with lost DC, thats why only one instance. However users will have to customize their desktops from scratch after rejoining another domain as a new user.  Can't belive there is no tools to cover this simple situation.

Comment: Partly, it's a security thing... you wouldn't want someone to simply grab that file onto a USB stick and be able to bring up your domain elsewhere.

Comment: "Can't belive there is no tools to cover this simple situation" - Tools like Windows Server Backup?